# Translate a CURL request into R?

Tags: r, curl, http-headers

I am trying to translate a CURL request into R. here's the CURL:

```
curl -v -u random_api_key -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET 'https://domain.freshdesk.com/api/v2/tickets'
```

I tried to turn this into

`require(RJSONIO)
tickets = fromJSON('https://domain.freshdesk.com/api/v2/tickets?u=random_api_key')`

But this is eliciting a server response:

`"invalid_credentials" "You have to be logged in to perform this action."`

So then I tried to use a different library and set headers explicitly:

```
library(httr)   
library(rjson)  
query <- "https://domain.freshdesk.com/api/v2/tickets"
getdata<-GET(query, query = list(User-Agent:"random_api_key", Content-Type:"application/json"))
fromJSON(content(getdata,type="text"))
```

But this is giving me the error:

`Error in named(list(...)) : object 'User' not found`

Not sure where to go from here. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You can't enter variable names like this in R: `User-Agent`, `Content-Type`; try using `"User-Agent"`, etc. instead.

Comment: The [curlconverter](https://cran.r-project.org/package=curlconverter) package is useful for these purposes.